# multi-column row in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, multicolumn

I would like to be able to use `multicolumn` inside an align environment, much like we can do in a `tabular` environment

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a &= e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} \\
    e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} &= a
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

In this case I would like to be able to put the `&` inside the exponent on the lhs of the second line, i.e. `e^{a+b+c+d+e+ & f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p}` but of course this is not allowed. I tried using `multicolumn` but this gave errors as well.

Of course I could align both equations to the left, but where I need it the situation is much more involving. Until now, I would put the ampersand in the second equation fully to the left, and manually adjust using negative spaces… But I wonder if there exists a better solution.

The most ideal situation would be something that allows me to put the `&` wherever I want, even inside brackets, but I would be happy with a multicolumn solution as well.

**EDIT**

What I try to achieve is something like

[image]

Comment: Why to use multicolumn and not alignat or aligned?

Comment: Or use `eqnarray`? *edit* I just saw [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align), so better use the aligned-commands (and I'll revise my documents).

Comment: I would not use alignment in this case, use `gather` and loose the `&`'s

Comment: Could we have an idea of the real equations, and what has to be aligned withwhat?

Comment: @Hackbard_C I remember that `eqnarray` is deprecated in favour of environments more flexible such as the `amsmath` or another packages for maths.

Comment: @Aradnix: not only more flexible, but also with a better horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the spacing in a `\phantom` way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    &\phantom{e^{a+b+c+d+{}}}a = e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} \\
    &e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} = a
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

if i have understood correctly what you have described, this will give that result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a &= e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} \\
    \rlap{$e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p}$}\phantom{e^{a+b+c+d+e+{}}} &= a
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

but somehow, i don't think it's what you really want ...

Comment: No indeed, I would like to move the full second line..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the optional argument of the`\MoveEqLeft` command, from `mathtools` to obtain experimetally what you want. In the equation where it's used, it replaces the ampersand and moves the equation a number of `em`s equal to the optional argument (2 by default).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a &= e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} \\
\MoveEqLeft[4.5] e^{a+b+c+d+e+ f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} = a
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this is exactly the same as writing `&\hspace*{-4.5em} e^{…}`, right? Because that's how I've always done it. It is the trial and error part that I try to avoid..

Comment: It's the same, except you don't have to write the ampersand. I'm afraid what you want can't be done in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

can be written as

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a &= e^{a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} \\ 
 ~{}\quad e^{a+b+c+d+e+ f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p} 
 &= a
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: alignedeq]